Delphi 11.3 with Android SDK 33
I only have access to Delphi 11.3 at the moment.
Google Developers portal have a requirement of SDK 33 now.
Is it possible to get 11.3 to work with SDK 33 ?
I installed Android Studio, managed to install SDK 33 with NDK 26.
(NDK 26 is highest version at the moment)
However, getting Delphi 11.3 to recognise SDK 33 is a challenge.
I'm not able to do it from Tools-Options-SDK
Has anyone done it successfully?  Or is upgrade to 12.0 an absolute must to be able to upload to Google Play Store (min sdk 33)?
thanks!

hi, the post does not relate to 11.3.  it seems sdk 33 is hard to install with Delphi 11.3

The SO answer I linked in my comment sounded like it was possible to enable API 33 in Delphi 11.2. My conclusion was that it therefore must also be possible in 11.3. As I don't know for sure, I deleted my comment.

An article ("Delphi Supports Android API 33 Via Yukon Beta") on the Embarcadero blog states:

RAD Studio 11.3 (...) does not offer the support for API level 33.

https://blogs.embarcadero.com/delphi-supports-android-api-33-via-yukon-beta/

Just wondering if anyone managed to find a workaround without going to Delphi 12.  Let's say how would community users be able to try out uploading any Android apps, if 11.3 doesn't support sdk 33?

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page

It clearly states that 11.3 supports Android 13 (sdk 33).
The question is how to configure Delphi 11.3 such that Android 13 works.  The is always the challenge with Embarcadero products.  They claim that it supports it, but it does not have a simple configuration page to show how to configure it.

I am absolutely flabbergasted …

You dont need to use Android Studio, i did this:
Tools > Options
Deployment > SDK Manager
SDK base path -> open that path then go "cmdline-tools\latest\bin"
open command prompt (admin just in case) then run 
"sdkmanager cmdline-tools;latest" this will create another dir named "latest-2" when done rename "latest" in "latest-back" or delete it and rename "latest-2" in "latest"
btw i tried "--update" but it didnt update.
"sdkmanager --list_installed"
with delphi 11.3 CE i had "build-tools;32.0.0" "platform-tools" (35.0.1) "platforms:android-32"
"sdkmanager platforms;android-33"
"sdkmanager build-tools;33.0.3"
"sdkmanager --list_installed" to check
now back in Tools > Options > Deployment > SDK Manager
change any directory with the old API number with the new one (zipalign, apksigner, aapt, SDK API)
now api 33 is installed but dont forget that you need to manually open "AndroidManifest.template.xml" and change the "%targetSdkVersion%"  to "33"

